# Dynamic Multi Directional Slider in SCSS/SASS without JS

Tags: html, css, sass

So I'm trying to make a slider using three radio buttons, and I am trying to get it to change direction depending on which way it is sliding. Is there a way to make it face left when you click a radio to the left, and face right when you click one to the right?

I have this code:

```
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    scale: .5;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: translate .5s cubic-bezier(.38,-0.01,.51,1);
}
.container input[id="a"]:checked ~ .slider {
    translate: 0 0;
    $dir: 1 !global;
    transform: $transform scalex($dir);
}
.container input[id="b"]:checked ~ .slider {
    translate: 107.5px 0;
    transform: $transform scalex($dir);
}
.container input[id="c"]:checked ~ .slider {
    translate: 225px;
    $dir: -1 !global;
    transform: $transform scalex($dir);
}
```

I tried using if statements but that doesn't seem to work either. Does anyone know if it is possible to accomplish this without JS and only HTML and SCSS? If there is another CSS preprocessor that can allow me to do this I will be happy to do so.